# How to resolve error "AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'serializer'?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark dataframe. I have some code in which I'm trying to convert the `dataframe` to an `rdd`, but I receive the following error:

> AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'serializer'

What can be the issue?

```
training, test = rescaledData.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
nb = NaiveBayes(smoothing=1.0, modelType="multinomial")
# Train a naive Bayes model.
model = nb.fit(rescaledData)

# Make prediction and test accuracy.
predictionAndLabel = test.rdd.map(lambda p: (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
accuracy = 1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(lambda pl: pl[0] == pl[1]).count() / test.count()
print('model accuracy {}'.format(accuracy))
```

Does anyone have any insight to why the statement `test.rdd` causes an error? The dataframe contains `Row object of (label, features)`.

Thanks