# 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'serializer' when evaluating a classifier in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache spark in batch mode. I have set up an entire pipeline that transforms text into TFIDF vectors and then predicts a boolean class using Logistic regression:

```
# Chain previously created feature transformers, indexers and regression in a Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, idf, 
                        labelIndexer, featureIndexer, lr])
#Fit the full model to the training data
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

#Predict test data 
predictions = model.transform(testData)
```

I can examine `predictions`, which is a spark dataframe, and it is what I expect it to be. 
Next, I want to see a confusion matrix, so I convert the scores and labels to a RDD and pass that to  BinaryClassificationMetrics():

```
predictionAndLabels = predictions.select('prediction','label').rdd
```

Finally, I pass that to the BinaryClassificationMetrics:

```
metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabels) #this errors out
```

Here's the error:

```
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'serializer'
```

This error is not helpful and searching for it raises a broad spectrum of issues. the only thing I've found that seems similar is this post which has no answers: [How to resolve error "AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'serializer'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327006/how-to-resolve-error-attributeerror-sparksession-object-has-no-attribute-se)

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For prosperity's sake, here's what I did to fix this. When I initiate the Spark Session and the SQL context, I was doing this, which is not right:

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('App Name').master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

This problem was resolved by doing this instead:

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('App Name').master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkContext=sc.sparkContext, sparkSession=sc)
```

I'm not sure why that needed to be explicit, and would welcome clarification from the community if someone knows.